# Adobe Illustrator Layers not behaving as they should

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, layers, transparency, error

I am tearing my hair out over this issue.

I'm working in Adobe Illustrator to design a logo and the layers are not behaving as they should - the text at the bottom of my image is the top layer, yet it is shown behind all the other layers:

[image: artwork in illustrator]

[image: layers panel]

I have tried all the solutions that I can find including overprint fill/stroke (disabled)

[image: overprint attributes panel]

and transparency effects (normal)

[image: transparency effects panel "for mental health"]
[image: transparency effects panel red circle][image: transparency effects panel "bells"]

Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT
Expanded layers
[image: expanded layers]

Comment: Can you expand the layers so we see there is no appearace applied to group or something.

Comment: @joojaa added above

Comment: @Scott Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... It certainly appears as though overprint is set for the blue type. But your layers aren't showing that appearance meatball. Groups won't show appearance attributes in the Layer panel unless appearance is applied to the group itself.

---

One thing is certain, the issue *must* be the type layer...

Check inside those three groups for the type in your Layer Panel screenshot. Select the **objects** and ensure overprint/blending isn't set for those.

My guess is that those type characters are either set to overprint or have a multiply or darken blending mode assigned.

Comment: had the right answer - an object *inside* a layer was set to multiply. Thanks!